# Grass i.landsat.acca says image is cloud free but it is not

Tags: grass-gis, landsat, masking, cloud-cover

I'm working on an area in Amazonia with high cloud persistance which makes global data on land cover quite useless at small scales, so I wanted to learn to process my own Landsat images, with GRASS functions.

I downloaded one Landsat 5 image from http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/,  corresponding to 7 raster files, one for each band;
- Imported them into GRASS;
- Applied i.landsat.toar function to get top of atmosphere reflectance : The full code line is *i.landsat.toar --o input=LT52270571991288CUB00_B output=LT52270571991288CUB00 metfile=/home/LT52270571991288CUB00_MTL.txt*.
- Finally, I applied i.landsat.acca function to the outputs of the previous function.

What I get is the following:
"Processing first pass...

Preliminary scene analysis:
* Desert index: 0.00
* Snow cover: -nan %
* Cloud cover: -nan %
* Temperature of clouds:
** Maximum: 0.00 K
** Mean (cold cloud): -nan K
** Minimum: 10000.00 K
Result: Scene cloud free
Removing ambiguous pixels..."

This suggests that the image is cloud free, which is difficult to see looking at the image, and checking the metadata I see that the cloud cover is 29%.

Is there a step that I missed somewhere? I tried with a neighbouring Landsat scene, using exactly the same code, and in that case the correct cloud cover is found (same as in the meta data file).

Comment: Can you add the full command used for 'i.landsat.toar' ?